# Accessing an array resulting from a JSON decoding in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this array which is a result of decoding JSON in PHP (the array's name is $data):

```
Array ( [books] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [author] => author name [comment] => this is a great book ) [1] => Array ( [author] => another name [comment] => a comment ) ) )
```

I am trying to access this array as follows:

```
$data->books[0]->author
```

for example or $data->books to get an array of the books including author or comment but neither is working, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: You are not using the correct notation for arrays. `$data['books'][0]['author']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When decoding a JSON object in PHP it will be represented as an (associative) array. This might be a little confusing at first since decoding a JSON object in JavaScript usually return a JavaScriptObject representation.

```
$data['books'][0]['author'];
```