# json response store in array using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

Hello I am getting json response from web using php curl. Response which I am getting is a bulk amount of data. Now I want to store some of the specific data into an array and print it in table form using php, like name, status, label etc. How can I do it?

```
$url = "";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);



echo ($result);


curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Please provide the code that show your try on solving the stated problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing an array resulting from a JSON decoding in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713036/accessing-an-array-resulting-from-a-json-decoding-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting a JSON response, use `json_decode()` to make it php readable.  To make it an array (I would), use the `true` parameter like `json_decode($result,true)` and then manipulate the date from that array.

[JSON-decode (php manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)